# Method Variable with Multiple User in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session-variables, static-methods

I would like to ask to you.

I build up the web application ASP.NET that used many of user.
For this code, I have defined a simple method, no "Set" and no "Get", Just simple general Method.

```
Public Sub Result(Byval a As String, ByVal hoursPump As Integer)

//The code

End Sub
```

As your experience, you know The static variable is dangerous if used many user in same time. So session is most recommended as variable. But, How about the method? Can it to use the session or not?

With this line :

```
Public Sub pumpigResult2(Byval a As String, ByVal hoursPump As Integer)
```

Is safe if I used **method with variable String, integer etc** like above method if running at one time in many user?

Thank you,

Comment: You can safely use a [`Shared`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) *method* in ASP.NET. Maybe [VB .NET Shared Function if called multiple times simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2519391/1115360) will help yuo.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hi Thank you very much for your help. Mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confused with one of the basic concepts of object oriented programming and Visual Basic isn't helping you any to learn about it. Check out this other stack overflow post that may help point you in the right direction:
[Static Method implementation in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032363/static-method-implementation-in-vb-net)